# difficulty plotting layer from shapefile in rstudio

Tags: r, gis, shapefile

I'm trying to load and plot a layer from a simple shapefile.  It is state boundaries in the US.  I can load it fine:

```
> library("sp","rgdal")

> shape = readOGR("/home/username/data/share/mapnik/world_boundaries/states_EPSG4326.shp", layer="states_EPSG4326")

    OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
    Source: "/home/username/data/share/mapnik/world_boundaries/states_EPSG4326.shp", layer:       "states_EPSG4326"
    with 2895 features and 9 fields
    Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
```

But it fails to plot:

```
> plot(shape)

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: Path drawing not available for this device
2: Path drawing not available for this device
3: Path drawing not available for this device
...
```

What am I missing?  Nothing shows up in the plot window. There is only the single layer in this shapefile.  I could plot it in qgis, which I am trying to find an alternative for.  R seems like a popular choice, but I'm not having much luck so far.  I googled this warning, but did not turn up anything useful.

**Edit:**
This same response is received with every shape file I have tried.  Here is a shapefile that I have verified responds the same way:

http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/pub/data/nationalatlas/statep010_nt00798.tar.gz

Here is the output of sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C           
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C       
 [7] LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C        
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_0.7-22 sp_1.0-2    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.2     lattice_0.20-10 tools_2.15.2
```

Also this is a gentoo system, the following use flags are enabled on dev-lang/R:

- X icu java jpeg nls openmp png readline tiff

The following use flags are not enabled (capabilities not compiled):

- -bash-completion -cairo -doc -lapack -minimal -perl -profile -static-libs -tk"

The only two that look suspicious to me are cairo and tk, are they needed for plotting?

I ran R from the terminal with similiar, but not exactly the same results:

```
> shape = readOGR("/home/username/Downloads/state/statep010.shp", layer="statep010")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "/home/username/Downloads/state/statep010.shp", layer: "statep010"
with 62 features and 9 fields
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
> plot(shape)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In polypath(x = mcrds[, 1], y = mcrds[, 2], border = border,  ... :
  Path drawing not available for this device
2: In polypath(x = mcrds[, 1], y = mcrds[, 2], border = border,  ... :
  Path drawing not available for this device
3: In polypath(x = mcrds[, 1], y = mcrds[, 2], border = border,  ... :
  Path drawing not available for this device
...
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without being able to reproduce your problem. Can you share the data somehow, such as via Dropbox or a file sharing service?

Comment: @SlowLearner, thanks I edited the original question with a link to a shape file, which cannot be plotted here.

Comment: @nomadicME I test your shape file under windows . it works and I have the map.

Comment: @nomadicME under Unix too it works!

Comment: @nomadicME I have downloaded the shape file and with your code `plot` gives the output one would expect. Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question; that may contain a clue.

Comment: works on my System (Ubuntu 64bit). Have you tried to run from command line?

Comment: @SlowLearner, I've provided the output of sessionInfo() in the original question.  Thanks.

Comment: @EDi, I tried it from the R command line (outside rstudio), and the results were similiar, but not exactly the same.  I placed the output in the original question.  Is cairo or tk compiled into R required to plot?  Thanks.

Comment: @nomadicME Your installation looks OK and up to date. Does `plot(shape, usePolypath = FALSE)` in RGui (the command line) make any difference?

Comment: @SlowLearner, that did it.  Thanks. That wasn't too bad for a first plot in R. :)  Any idea why I need to add that switch when everyone seems to work fine with the defaults?

Comment: @nomadicME It has to do with the interaction between X11 and the `sp` library when drawing polygons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `plot(shape, usePolypath = FALSE)` as described in [this thread](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/New-use-of-polypath-in-package-sp-causing-a-problem-td7580716.html) by Roger Bivand.

Comment: As stated in the link you provided, if I issue this command: `set_Polypath(FALSE)` then I can go ahead an use `plot(shape)` which is much more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in plotting administrative boundaries only, can't you just use data sources provided by some R packages?

`maps` provide global administrative areas. You can retrieve country boundaries as well. See the example used with ggplot [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_map.html).

`dismo` provide data from [GADM database](http://www.gadm.org/). You can retrive data by country and level.

```
library(maps)
library(raster)

admlim <-getData('GADM', country='USA', level=1)
proj4string(admlim) <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')
# plot(admlim) # plain plot
# dataframe for ggplot()
# This will take a long, long time for USA level 1 data from GADM
t.adm <- fortify(admlim)
ggplot(aes(long, lat, group = group), data = t.adm,
  colour = 'grey20', fill = NA) +
  geom_path() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=(-2:2) * 30) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=(-4:4) * 45) +
  coord_map('ortho', orientation=c(41, -74, 0))
```

[image: NY centered map of usa]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could solve it by compiling R again after installing libcairo2-dev and libpango1.0-dev

On debian:

```
sudo apt install libcairo2-dev
sudo apt install libpango1.0-dev
```

I am sure that in particular libpango1.0-dev was missing before. Then I used

```
./configure --prefix=/.../.../R --with-cairo
make && make install
```

and that fixed it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are great! Missing pango was the reason. Make absolutely sure you have `pango-devel` installed before compiling R. Also the `./configure` results of R will tell you nothing whether pango is available (only cairo is there). Thank you so much for this answer!